# Professor Grinch's telephone number

Tags: combinatorics

Professor Grinch's telephone number is 6328363. Mickey remembers the collection of digits but not their order, expect that he knows the first 6 is before the first 3. How many arrangements of these digits with this constraint are there?

I am not for sure how to answer this question.

Comment: I don't think we can assume that the first 3 comes *straight* after the first 6.

Comment: That is what I am having troubles with. The first three doesn't have to come straight after the first 6

Comment: **Hint:** Ignore the 8 and 2 for the moment. Compare: ${\text{How many will have the first of two 6 before the first of three 3, versus}\\\text{How many will have the first of three 3 before the first of two 6?}}$

Comment: But doesn't that ignore the constraint of having the 6 before the 3? I am sorry if that sounds like a stupid question.

Answer (score 1):

There are $7$ digits, and of the $7!$ permutations, $2/5$ of the permutations have $6$ come before $3$. Furthermore, with two $6$'s and three $3$'s, the permutation overcounts the arrangements by $2!\cdot3!$ times.

So providing I didn't make a mistake, we have

$$\frac{2\cdot7!}{5\cdot2!\cdot3!}=168$$